# Python TimedRotatingFileHandler - PID in Log File name - Best Approach

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7, error-logging

I wish to start multiple instances (Processes) of the Python Program and I want each one of them to write to their own log file.

The processes will be restarted atleast once daily.

So i arrived at the following code.

```
logHandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),'logs/LogFile_'+str(os.getpid())+'.log'),when="midnight", backupCount=7)
```

1. Will this code maintain 7 Backups for each PID?
2. Is there a better way to split this so that my disk does not fill up with useless
   files? Give that the PID might be unique for the processes over months.
3. Is there a better approach to doing this?

What I would ideally like to have is that the logs pertaining to only 1 Week are maintained. Can this be done using TimeRotatingFileHander without having to write a separate Purge/Delete script?

Comment: Hey! did my answer actually address your question? Let me know if I missed the mark -- the no acceptance is like a loose thread :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, this will maintain 7 backups, or a weeks worth of logs, for each unique log path.
2. Rotating file handlers are the correct way to put a limit on logs.
3. As I said, rotating file handlers are the correct approach. I suppose you could use a `RotatingFileHandler`, but that rotates when the log hits a size, rather than at a particular time, so it doesn't allow you to specify a weeks worth of logs.

I'm a bit confused by how you're keeping the pid for a given process constant giving that the 'processes will be restarted at least once daily'. A stronger guarantee that each process has a unique log path is to provide it explicitly as an argument, e.g. `python script --log-file="$(pwd)/logs/LogFileProcX.log"`